# Paypal Adaptive Payment - Error 580023

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to execute a payment from PAY_KEY to a Paypal ID. Below is my sample code :

```
$PayRequestFields = array(
    'ActionType' => 'PAY',      
    'CancelURL' => $dataArray['cancel_url'],
    'CurrencyCode' => $dataArray['currency'],
    'FeesPayer' => 'SENDER',        
    'IPNNotificationURL' => '',         
    'Memo' => '',               
    'Pin' => $dataArray['pin'],     
    'PreapprovalKey' => $dataArray['sender_pre_approval_key'], 
    'ReturnURL' => $dataArray['return_url'],        
    'ReverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError' => '',      
    'SenderEmail' => '',                    
    'TrackingID' => ''                  
);

$ClientDetailsFields = array(
    'CustomerID' => '',                     
    'CustomerType' => '',                   
    'GeoLocation' => '',                    
    'Model' => '',                      
    'PartnerName' => ''                 
);

$FundingTypes = array('ECHECK', 'BALANCE', 'CREDITCARD');   

$Receivers = array();
$Receiver = array(
    'Amount' => $dataArray['primary_reciever_amount'],  
    'Email' => $dataArray['primary_reciever'],      
    'InvoiceID' => '',                  
    'PaymentType' => 'SERVICE',                 
    'PaymentSubType' => '',                 
    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => ''), 
    'Primary' => 'FALSE'                                 
);
array_push($Receivers,$Receiver);

$SenderIdentifierFields = array(
    'UseCredentials' => ''                          
);

$AccountIdentifierFields = array(
    'Email' => '',                              
    'Phone' => array('CountryCode' => '', 'PhoneNumber' => '', 'Extension' => '')
);

$PayPalRequestData = array(
    'PayRequestFields' => $PayRequestFields, 
        'ClientDetailsFields' => $ClientDetailsFields, 
        //'FundingTypes' => $FundingTypes, 
        'Receivers' => $Receivers, 
        'SenderIdentifierFields' => $SenderIdentifierFields, 
        'AccountIdentifierFields' => $AccountIdentifierFields
    );
    $PayPalResult = $PayPal->Pay($PayPalRequestData);
```

When I am executing this code, getting an error `"580023"` that says `"The fee payer SENDER cannot be used with this preapproval"`.

Please guide me for this.

Comment: I have never used this particular interface or gotten this particular message but it sounds pretty clear to me. Sounds like there is some policy in place that for this pre approval, the sender cannot be asked to pay the fee.  Change that parameter of the request and see if it works. If it does, you don't have a programming issue. If you want to know why the original request was deemed invalid then you should ask PayPal, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using the Chain Payments then FeePayer as " SENDER " is not allowed . You can check the documentation for more info [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/):

```
**feesPayer xs:string (Optional) The payer of PayPal fees.
```

Allowable values are:

```
 SENDER – Sender pays all fees (for personal, implicit simple/parallel payments; do not use for chained or unilateral payments)

PRIMARYRECEIVER – Primary receiver pays all fees (chained payments only)

EACHRECEIVER – Each receiver pays their own fee (default, personal and unilateral payments)

SECONDARYONLY – Secondary receivers pay all fees (use only for chained payments with one secondary receiver)**
```